# Identify email address from link in an email

Tags: php, email, token, mandrill

Right now, we're identifying the recipient as a user by adding his/her email address to the URL of the link inside of the email. For example, a link in an email might be: `http://something.com/?recipientEmail=cool_guy@aol.com`

However, a problem was just presented - if the recipient of the email forwards the email, anyone that gets that message is also identified as the correct recipient when they click the correct link.

What other ways are there to identify the email address of the person who clicked the link? Or some other info that may solve the problem?

Comment: You could use a hash value that corresponds with the E-Mail internally on your servers - that would take care of the privacy problem.   There is, however, no way of telling whether it's the actual user visiting the link, or someone they forwarded it to.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with all of the differences, but can you even use POST from inside an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not exactly.

What you can do is use cookies to track the individual people who click your link, then assume that the first individual who clicks your link is the owner of the email that it was sent to, and that any other person is someone it was forwarded to.

What you can't do is determine who those other people are. You can only determine that they are probably different from the main recipient.

Comment: That was pretty much what I thought I would have to do. Bummer..I wish there was a sure way to know.